# Compare a List of files in java

Tags: java, oop, javafx

I am trying to implement a JavaFx Application where the filename of an mp4 and the filename of an png are compared, and if they are equal or one contains the other, right now there is a sysout.

So far I am using two loops to go through the lists of files and I am retrieving both files, but there is one problem: I have more pngs than mp4s, and that is why I am getting an ArrayOutOfBounds exception. I could not really find a workaround for this. The problem lies in the final if statement.

```
public void videoLoop() {
    File videoDirectory = new File("C:\\Users\\Hasan\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Smart-Moniesta\\Smart-Moniesta-Raspberry-Pi\\src\\ressources\\videos");
    File[] listOfFiles = videoDirectory.listFiles();
    File imgDirectory = new File("C:\\Users\\Hasan\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Smart-Moniesta\\Smart-Moniesta-Raspberry-Pi\\src\\ressources\\images");
    File[] imglistOfFiles = imgDirectory.listFiles();

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <= listOfFiles.length - 1; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            System.out.println("File aus der i Schleife " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        }
    }
    for (j = 0; j <= imglistOfFiles.length - 1; j++) {
        if (imglistOfFiles[j].isFile()) {
            System.out.println("File Bilder aus der j Schleife: " + imglistOfFiles[j].getName());
        }
    }
    if (listOfFiles[i].getName().contains(imglistOfFiles[j].getName())) {
        System.out.println("Vergleich klappt" + listOfFiles[i].getName());
    } else {
        System.out.println("KLappt nicht");
    }
}
```

Comment: in the last ```if``` condition, where are you taking values of ```i``` and ```j```. It is taking the last values of ```i``` and ```j``` and hence ```ArrayOutOfBounds ```

Comment: oh, now I understand. How could I do it so it will compare it from start to end? What I want to achieve is, whenever the code finds something with the same name or contains a part of it, it will render an image.

Comment: you can nest the for loops and compare there and give conditions for when a certain array is fully traversed so that you wont get ```ArrayOutOfBounds``` exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the second for loop to be nested inside the first loop. and your last if condition should be inside the inner for loop.

You also need another condition in your for loop where you check if the second file name contains the first one.

Comment: I know this should have been a comment but I do not have sufficient rep to com.